# How to convert to String a elements of each object from an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object, like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "771276",       
        "Name": "John",        
        "Subject": [
            {
                "Name": "Subject 1"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Subject 2"
            }
        ]
    },
        {
        "ID": "771277",       
        "Name": "Mary",        
        "Subject": [
            {
                "Name": "Subject 80"
            }
        ]
    },
    .....   
]
```

How can I convert `Subject` element from each object to a String with elements separated by comma?

Getting the first object as example, I hope the result:

```
{
    "ID": "771276",       
    "Name": "John",        
    "Subject": "Subject 1, Subject 2"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A combination of `.map()` and `.join()` sounds like a reasonable approach.  Did you try anything?

Comment: `data.map(({ID,Name,Subject})=>({ID,Name,Subject:Subject.map(s=> s.Name).join(', ')}))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the help of the `.map()` and `.join()` methods of arrays.

For example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "ID": "771276",
    "Name": "John",
    "Subject": [
      {
        "Name": "Subject 1"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Subject 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": "771277",
    "Name": "Mary",
    "Subject": [
      {
        "Name": "Subject 80"
      }
    ]
  },
]

const result = data.map(({
  ID,
  Name,
  Subject
}) => ({
  ID,
  Name,
  Subject: Subject.map(sub => sub.Name).join(', ')
}))

console.log("Result", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.map ()` and `.join ()` functions should help you achieve the desired outcome. `.map ()` can transform the array of objects to an array of strings, while `.join ()` will convert the resulting array to a string.

To demonstrate, take for example this array of objects:

```
const Bands = 
[
    {
        ID: 1,
        Name: 'KMFDM',
        Members:
        [
            {
                Name: 'Sascha Konietzko'
            },
            {
                Name: 'Lucia Cifarelli'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        ID: 2,
        Name: 'Green Day',
        Members:
        [
            {
                Name: 'Billie Joe Armstrong'
            },
            {
                Name: 'Tré Cool'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

To convert band members to a string, all you need to is the following one-line operation: `Bands.map (Band => ({ID: Band.ID, Name: Band.Name, Members: Band.Members.map (Member => Member.Name).join (', ')}));`

And voilà!

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include some example code so that OP (and others!) can see how to do what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

In js is quiete simple, apply to your code and leave a comment if something is not clear!

```
data["Subject"].map(subject => subject["Name"]).join(", ");
```